# MATLAB subplot function sys too many input arguments

Tags: matlab

I have script in MATLAB that uses the subplot function. Now I know that it takes 3 arguments minimum to work as I have seen in the MATLAB docs. However, it give an error saying too many input arguments. This is the code

```
%% ================= Part 5: Image Compression ======================


% Find closest cluster members
idx = findClosestCentroids(X, centroids);

% Essentially, now we have represented the image X as in terms of the
% indices in idx. 

% We can now recover the image from the indices (idx) by mapping each pixel
% (specified by its index in idx) to the centroid value
X_recovered = centroids(idx,:);

% Reshape the recovered image into proper dimensions
X_recovered = reshape(X_recovered, img_size(1), img_size(2), 3);

% Display the original image 
subplot(1, 2, 1);
imagesc(A); 
title('Original');

% Display compressed image side by side
subplot(1, 2, 2);
imagesc(X_recovered)
title(sprintf('Compressed, with %d colors.', K));
```

At the '%Display the original image section', it is giving an error saying

```
Error using subplot
Too many input arguments.
Error in ex7 (line 162)
subplot(1,2,1);
```

I cannot understand why MATLAB will be giving such an error. Please explain.

Comment: Is there a file in the local directory called `subplot`?

Comment: Tell the result of which subplot

Answer (score 1):

it look like you have another function with the same name. 
search for sub function in the same file or search for global file:

```
which subplot -all
```